# I want to use onclick more images with javascript

Tags: javascript

There is one html page and I have a lot of same images. I want to add alot of same images and when I click one I want it to change. If I have one picture these codes OK! but if I have a lot of same pictures How can I do this? Please can you show me a solution way ?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<style>
#im{
    margin-left:250px;
    margin-right: 0px;

}
</style>
<body>


<script>
function changeImage()
{
element=document.getElementById('im')
if (element.src.match("image"))
  {
  element.src="picture1.png";
  }
else
  {
  element.src="image1.png";
  }
}
</script>
<img id="im" onclick="changeImage()"
src="picture1.png">



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to do?

Comment: Ok. I have a html page (I use jinja2) and I have 1000 entry. I must add same image for every entry. How can I add 1000 image and change it with onclick() function. Can I do with createElement or something else ?

Comment: @Sergio I think you had the right idea before. Just maybe expand on your answer. And to satisfy critics, include an alternative for unobtrusive JavaScript.

Comment: if there is one image I understand but I have a lot of image that I must add to html and when I click on it must change like example I give in my question. ( sorry for my bad English)

Comment: @Sergio Then again... Given the accepted answer, I think both of us had it pegged wrong. :)

Comment: Guys you can misunderstand because of my bad English : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// store image names here
var images = [
    "picture1.png",
    "picture2.png",
    "picture3.png",
    "picture4.png",
    "picture5.png",
];
// preload images to reduce lag time
var imageArray = [];
for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
    imageArray[i] = new Image();
    imageArray[i].src = images[i];
}
// the change function
var index = 0;
function changeImage()
{
    var element = document.getElementById('im');
    element.src = images[index];
    index++;
    if (index === images.length) index = 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: To keep it cycling, you'll want to reset `index` to `0` at some point. Possibly, `index++; if (index === images.length) index = 0;`